# Laravel 5.3 error-Use of undefined constant kadmin - assumed 'kadmin' (View: C:\wamp64\www\admin\resources\views\kadmin\layout.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel 5.3 to build an a page but after specifying a route and using it in a browser, the following error appears

> "Use of undefined constant strah - assumed 'strah' (View: C:\wamp64\www\admin\resources\views\strah\layout.blade.php)".

I have created a layout.blade.php file and has the following line which i think is the root cause

```
@include(strah.header.header)
```

Do I have any wrong syntax?
What can I do to get it running?

```
Route::get('/dashboard',function() {
      return view('strah.layout');

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enclose the include value within quotes. Try :

```
@include('strah.header.header')
```

Comment: After changing it to that, everything is good

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
@include(strah.header.header)
```

to

```
@include("strah.header.header")
```